# How can i remove duplicate values from an Echoed table?

Tags: php, join, duplicates

I have managed to create a JOIN query for three tables and can successfully echo out the results in a echoed table, here is my code:

```
<?php 

$sql="SELECT a.product_id, a.Options_id, b.product_name, b.product_price, c.Options_name, c.Price_diff
FROM ProductOptions a
JOIN Products b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
JOIN Options c ON a.Options_id = c.Options_id
ORDER BY product_name DESC";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result)

{

echo "An error occurred ".mysql_error();

exit;

}

echo "<table border=1>\n<tr><th></th><th bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\">Name</th><th>Flavors & Size</th><th bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\">Price</th><th>Price Difference</th><th bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\"></th></tr>\n";

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


$name = $line["product_name"];

$price = $line["product_price"];

$options=$line["Options_name"];

$difference=$line["Price_diff"];


echo "<tr><td></td><td bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\">$name</td><td>$options</td> <td bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\">£$price</td><td>£$difference</td><td bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\"></td></tr>\n";

}

echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

My table works but it shows duplicate entries for `product_name` and I do not know how to remove them.

Comment: JOIN Options c ON a.Options_id = c.Options_id
GROUP BY product_name
ORDER BY product_name DESC

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/group-by-modifiers.html) clause in your query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.product_id, a.Options_id, b.product_name, b.product_price, c.Options_name, c.Price_diff
        FROM ProductOptions a
        JOIN Products b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
        JOIN Options c ON a.Options_id = c.Options_id
        GROUP BY product_name
        ORDER BY product_name DESC";
```

Comment: Doing GROUP BY works but its taken away some of my sizes and flavors and has given it just ONE of everything, one flavor and one size.. when some products have multiple flavors and sizes

Comment: Can anyone help me further? The GROUP BY clause has taken away the duplicate product names but has only given each product name either 1 flavor or 1 size..

Comment: Just add the fields which are needed for your group by seperating them with commas. If your column is named "flavor" add GROUP BY product_name, flavor

Comment: That doesn't work, if i add Options_name (which is where the flavor an sizes are listed) then the duplicated product names reappear